# Inconsistent styling of tabs?

Tags: bug, design

I'm new to this SE site, but I noticed some inconsistency in the way that 'tabs' are styled on this site.

Here's a screenshot from the questions list:
[image: no spacing]

And most other areas of the site look very much like this. However, on any [user profile](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/users/36519/p-s-w-g) page, there's some extra padding between the tabs and the line below them:
[image: extra spacing]

Note that this may be observed on the main site and on the meta site. I'm not sure if this was intentional or not, but it looks like a bug to me. I think it should at least be consistent across the site.